# Can't write multipe files to Zip file

Tags: go, zip

I'm trying to write a CSV file and an image to a zipfile.  The images get writte, and the CSV file gets created, but it empty (0 bytes in size).   Here is the simplest code I could reproduce:

```
func PipeZIP() error {
    pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(pipeWriter)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        defer func() {
            wg.Done()
            zipWriter.Close()
            pipeWriter.Close()
        }()

        f1, err := zipWriter.Create("test")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        f2, err := zipWriter.Create("test.jpg")
        object, err := minioClient.GetObject("test", "some_key", minio.GetObjectOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err", err)
        }

        if _, err := io.Copy(f2, object); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(f1)
        csvWriter.Write([]string{"hello", "there", "world"})

        csvWriter.Flush()

    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        _, err := minioClient.PutObject("test", "somerandomname.zip", pipeReader, -1, minio.PutObjectOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    return nil
}
```

If I comment out the image part, the CSV file gets written.  If I leave it in, the images get written, but now the CSV file is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://godoc.org/archive/zip#Writer.Create) says:  *The file's contents must be written to the io.Writer before the next call to Create, CreateHeader, or Close.*   To meet this requirement, move all operation for `f1` before the operations for `f2` or vice versa.

Comment: Also, the second goroutine can be merged into the main goroutine and all use of the wait group can be removed.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Aha, it looks like my problem is more complicated than I thought.  Basically, in my real example I need to write to to the zip in a for loop, but also write CSV entries in that same for loop.  The only way I know of to accomplish that is by returning some data form the for loop and then writing out, but I was hoping I could just do everything directly in the for loop.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll have to [buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) the CSV then, or build a slice and use [WriteAll](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.WriteAll), and add it to the archive after the loop.